# Why does navigation controller not appear in run time?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, appdelegate

I use Xcode 6. I have several view controllers connecting together with present Seques(push). I set the initial point to navigation controller. My app loads with view or table view controller based on one circumstance. I embedded in Navigation controller using the editor menu. I can see the navigation controller before running, but it disappear in run time. Does any one know the reason?

I am suspicious to this part of my code in applicationdidfinishlaunchwithoption cause this problem:

```
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger RegisteredFlagNumber = [defaults integerForKey:@"RegisteredFlag"];
    bool isLoggedIn= (RegisteredFlagNumber==1) ? true:false;
    NSString *storyboardId = isLoggedIn ? @"MainIdentifier" : @"LoginIdentifier";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *initViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:storyboardId];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = initViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

but I do not know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set it as `Initial ViewController` at IB.

> In the attributes inspector look for the View Controller or Window Controller category and set the Is Initial View Controller checkbox.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/chapters/SetInitialController.html

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:
I add it programatically in applicationdidfinishluchwithoption:

```
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger RegisteredFlagNumber = [defaults integerForKey:@"RegisteredFlag"];
    bool isLoggedIn= (RegisteredFlagNumber==1) ? true:false;
    NSString *storyboardId = isLoggedIn ? @"MainIdentifier" : @"LoginIdentifier";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
```

//here it is the changes for getting result

```
  UIViewController *initViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:storyboardId];
    UINavigationController *navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:initViewController];



  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

//here it is the changes for getting result

```
    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```